# Unreachable Code in Java Code?

Tags: java

I have a program that has one error and I can't find out how to fix it. The error tells me that this line is unreachable code.

```
continue;inputUrname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter User Name");
```

Why is this?

```
switch ((str1 = loginChoice).hashCode())
  {
  case 73596745: 
    if (str1.equals("Login")) {
      break;
    }
    break;
  case 278621961: 
    if (!str1.equals("Create Account"))
    {
      continue;inputUrname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter User Name");
      if (inputUrname != null) {
        inputPass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Password");
      }
```

Comment: It helps to only put one statement per line. What do you think `continue` does?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this?

Because the `continue` statement makes the following assignment unreachable.

A `continue` tells Java unconditionally end the current loop iteration ....

I suspect that the `continue;` is an accidental insertion, though it is also possible that this is decompiled code and the decompiler has made a mistake.  (This is not unusual, and it is one of those things that you just have to deal with.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you use the keyword continue, which tells the program to break the case. Thus, anything after that will not possibly execute.  Delete the continue statement and your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`continue` statement in Java is used to skip the part of loop. Unlike break statement it does not terminate the loop , instead it skips the remaining part of the loop and control again goes to check the condition again.

Due to this reason you get the code is unreachable error.